# DC motors stall in toy car project

Tags: dc-motor

[image]

I am a total newbie. I am trying to make a toy car with two geared DC motors and two LEDs, all connected in parallel. I am trying to power everything with a 9 V battery, but I am running into problems.

1. When placed on the ground, the car docent have enough torque
2. Even when not placed on the ground, the motors slow down and stall after about 30 seconds. After switching it off and starting again, the motors run well and then again stall. The battery gets quite hot.
3. I tried measuring current across the motors with a multimeter. I get around 50 mA. Sometimes, the motors stall as soon as I bring the probes in contact with the motor ends, so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

After reading up a bit, I think the problem is that the 9 V battery is not able to give enough current to power the two motors. The motors I am using have these specs (copied from [here](https://robu.in/product/100-rpm-dual-shaft-bo-motor-straight/))

```
Operating Voltage (VDC): 3~12
No Load Current: 40-180 mA.
```

I am going to try using 4 AA batteries in series. I read that AA batteries have a much higher current capacity compared to the 9 V.

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me understand what's going on and if using 4 AA cells in series will help.

Comment: Four AA batteries in series gives you only 6V - six AA batteries in series should give you 9V (similar to that Duracell 9V battery in your photo). Your ideas about batteries are good. It is difficult to assess if series-connected AA batteries will provide enough current to prevent stalling - but you're on the right path in trying.

Comment: I don't see any resistors in your PIC. LEDs need series resistors!

Comment: You should add a "driver" with PWM capabilities ...

Comment: You measure current by putting the meter in SERIES with the load, not across. A 9V battery such as you have there is just not suitable for driving a heavy load such as a motor.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.  Yes, I was hoping the 6V (4 AA in series) would be enough.  I believe that these leds, have built in resistors.  Thanks for pointing out my stupidity in measuring current :) I did not know about PWM drivers. Am reading up about this.

Comment: Update -  using 4AA cells in series did the job ! Thanks everyone